# Integrating a Partial Derivative

Tags: calculus, integration

Would I be right to think that $$\int dx \,\,\,\frac{\partial}{\partial x} f(x,y)=f(x,y)$$
Or are there pathological cases?

Comment: It seems correct to me.

Comment: Up to a constant, yes. Note that to be differentiable, a function must be continuous, which guarantees it is Riemann integrable.

Comment: Up to the fact that the result might be $f(x,y)+C$, it looks reasonable.

Comment: It depends on what you mean with $\int dx \,\,\,\frac{\partial}{\partial x} f(x,y)=f(x,y)$. If you mean that that equality is shorthand for "differentiating with respect to $x$ on both sides gives an equality", then it is correct. But there's another reasonable interpretation and accordidng to that one, it is wrong.

Comment: [Related](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/380527/if-frac-partial-varphi-partial-x-fx-y-frac-partial-varphi-partial-y).

Answer (score 44, accepted):

If $x$ and $y$ are independent variables (and thus the $y$ is held constant during integration), then it is true that

$$
\int \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} dx = f(x,y) + C(y)
$$
where $C(y)$ is equivalent to the integration constant for the univariate case. As such, up to the "constant", you are right.

If $y=y(x)$, then it is not that simple. For instance, if $f(x,y)=x^2-xy+y^2$ and you integrate along the line $y=2x$, then you are actually integrating
$$
\int \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} dx = \int (2x-y) dx = \int 0 dx = 0
$$