# Is the definite integral of this partial derivative equal to the function itself over the interval?

Tags: integration, partial-derivative

Is the solution of a generic integral of the form
$$
\int_0^t \frac{\partial f(x(y),y)}{\partial y} dy
$$
where $x(y)$ is unknown, simply equal to
$$f(x(t),t) - f(x(0),0)?$$
And if it is not always the case, when does it hold? I previously found a related question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/754742/integrating-a-partial-derivative).

Comment: The related question applies to your case only when your $x$ is a constant. Try $f(x,y)=xy$ and $x(y)=y\,.$

Comment: Therefore in my case integration can be done, right?

Comment: It can but the integral is not $f(x(t),t)-f(x(0),0)\,.$

Comment: @KurtG. Is there a way to identify its solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the fundamental theorem of calculus, $$\int_0^t\frac{\mathrm{d}f(x(y),y)}{\mathrm{d}y}\,\mathrm{d}y=f(x(t),t)-f(x(0),0).$$ To see why, just let $g(y):=f(x(y),y),$ and proceed from there. By the chain rule, $$\frac{\mathrm{d}f(x(y),y)}{\mathrm{d}y}=\frac{\partial{f(x(y),y)}}{\partial{y}}+\frac{\partial{f(x(y),y)}}{\partial{x}}x'(y).$$ Therefore, $$\int_0^t\frac{\partial{f(x(y),y)}}{\partial{y}}\,\mathrm{d}y=f(x(t),t)-f(x(0),0)-\int_0^t\frac{\partial{f(x(y),y)}}{\partial{x}}x'(y)\,\mathrm{d}y.$$ This is the formula you need. Whether this is helpful or not is a separate subject of discussion, of course.

Answer (score 1):

The formula
$$
\int_0^t\partial_yf(x(y),y)\,dy=f(x(t),t)-f(x(0),0)
$$
holds for all $t$ *if and only if*

- $x$ does not depend on $y\,,$ or, $f(x,y)$ does not depend on $x\,.$

Proof. Differentiating the formula with respect to $t$ gives
$$
\partial_yf(x(t),t)=x'(t)\partial_xf(x(t),t)+\partial_yf(x(t),t)\,.
$$
This can be simplified to
$$
0=x'(t)\partial_xf(x(t),t)\,.
$$
So either $x'(t)=0$ or $\partial_xf(x(t),t)=0\,.$

The reverse implication is shown in the linked question for $x$ being constant.
When $f$ does not depend on $x$ it is the well known fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: In case x did not depend on y, the formula would hold up to a constant that does not depend on y but might depend on x, right?

Comment: In the link they consider an *indefinite* integral wich brings up that constant. We here consider a *definite* integral from zero to $t\,.$ No constant.